# How can I secure an outward door swing to be safe inside without drilling holes?

Tags: outdoor, swing

I want to feel safe inside a room that swings door outward. How do I secure a outward door swing to be safe inside at night without drilling a hole into the wood. is there a portable outward swing long available for sale? thanks !

Comment: This is your front door (main entry) into the house?

Comment: Is there anything that holds the door closed at the moment, or is it truly just flapping in the breeze?  Because if it has a non-locking doorknob or handle that just latches right now, probably that one could be replaced with one that does lock without drilling any additional holes; you'd simply reuse the holes that are already there.

Comment: Also, adding a picture of the door to your post would be helpful.

Comment: Please provide details about your hardware. Your question is too broad as it is. We can't offer specific advice, and most such doors already have security measures built in.

Comment: Drilling a hole in your trim is the easiest place to repair.

Answer (score 2):

I saw a device that looked much like a key hole in a steel plate. It slipped over the doorknob and it’s weight held it in place. I thought that was a good idea, even made out of 1/2” plywood if there was a few inches above and below it would be as strong as most cheap lock sets.
The keyhole looked like it was made with 2 different sized hole saws one that was larger than the handle and one just slightly larger than the shaft if you pulled on the door it did not move much. That would be something that could be made but I have not seen a commercial one.

Comment: Wow 2 down votes with no explanation. technical for some I guess. It would prevent a door from being pulled open without hardware.

Comment: I like this idea for an outswing door, simple and effective, kinda like a 2 x 4 across the inside of a inswing door. maybe folks are having trouble visualizing the idea by your description...

Comment: @jimmy fix-it . Yes maybe I should have said like a do not disturb sign that they hang on doorknobs but a bit larger. But then ?? Just can’t fix stupid.

Answer (score 1):

Look up "Security Hinge Pins". These prevent the attack of simply knocking out the hinge pin. These replace one of the existing hinge screws, then you remove the screw that would face that one, so no additional holes are required. Either that, or get security hinges. Those work the same way, but as a built-in knob in the hinge.

After that, just get a regular locking handle. (And deadbolt if appropriate.) I think they're all reversible.

Comment: I understand not being able to knock out hinge pins but the op was talking about not drilling the wood did not discuss the pins.

Comment: Good idea. up voted.

Answer (score 0):

That's the problem. You may have to sacrifice not drilling to have security. Here's my most recent idea:

I had a vision (an epiphany if you will!). Wrapping a 12 gauge solid core wire around the door knob stem (so it's behind the knob part).

pull 24 inches of slack from the wrapped stem and wrap it around a 1/2 inch EMT conduit (or 3/4" EMT). The EMT should be long enough to span the width of the door jamb.

Pull 24 inches more from the EMT and wrap that again around the door knob stem.

Twist the EMT until it tightens against the jamb walls; as you'd tighten a tourniquet. Voila! Door can not be pulled open due to the EMT being braced against the inside wall.

It can be removed simply by unscrewing the wire via the EMT. no holes drilled. Secured by compression.

Comment: Every one of these require putting holes in the wood exactly what the op did not want.

Comment: Ed- check out my updated answer.

Comment: I will stick with a solid form of a keyhole block or like a do not disturb sign the correct size drops over the knob and it’s done, but that would be fun to see some one try.